# how to get all ids from file by parsing line by line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I have a file containing a format of lines like

`RecoveryJob - ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Starting recovery for Plan{id='e7a74224-f826-4608-9d0d-03bf18e775f6', planId='1234567890'}`

I have to parse this file line by line and fetch the id from this line which is `e7a74224-f826-4608-9d0d-03bf18e775f6`

and save it to different file.

Comment: What's your problem? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with regular expressions

```
import re

s = "RecoveryJob - ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ Starting recovery for Plan{id='e7a74224-f826-4608-9d0d-03bf18e775f6', planId='1234567890'}"
re.search(r".*{id='(.*)',", s).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are more pythonic ways of doing this, but is is one possible solution:

```
file = open("your_document.txt", "r")
text = file.read()
file.close()

index = text.find("id") + 4
id = text[index:index + 36]
print(id)
```